# "by.repeater(" ").column(" ")" does not work for customized angularjs directives

Tags: angularjs, protractor

When I'm trying to get the customer display name (Please refer below page source) using:

by.repeater("vt_query in bo.data.vt_query").column("vt_query.display_name")

result is an error message for the absence of any matches. How should I proceed?

```
<tr ng-repeat="vt_query in bo.data.vt_query" mi-search-results-highlight="" class="ng-scope">
    <td class="col-sm-5 layoutColumn">
        <cg-template id="custCard" cg-template-name="media" class="media ng-scope" cg-template-type="Frame">
            <div class="media">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <div id="media-object" 
                         mi-search-repeater-row-collapse="" 
                         ng-click="ExpandCollapse()" 
                         class="ng-scope cg-muted-block icon icon-medical-professional icon-1-75x"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="media-body" class="ng-scope media-body">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div name="mimicEdit" 
                             class="clearfix " 
                             cg-bind="vt_query.display_name" 
                             cg-key="vt_query/display_name" 
                             cg-link="pres/summary.cdl?customerid=7000042000000177" 
                             cg-link-type="url" 
                             cg-link-protocol="http" 
                             cg-link-entity="vt_query" 
                             cg-label="false" 
                             cg-read-only="true">
                            <span id="control" 
                                  class="cg-link cg-link" 
                                  ng-bind="vt_query.display_name" 
                                  cg-link="pres/summary.cdl?customerid=7000042000000177" 
                                  cg-link-type="url" 
                                  cg-link-protocol="http" 
                                  cg-link-entity="vt_query">Abbas, Syed</span>
                            <!-- ngIf: false -->
                        </div>
                        <div name="mimicEdit" 
                             class="clearfix " 
                             cg-bind="vt_query.main_customer_name" 
                             cg-key="vt_query/main_customer_name" 
                             cg-label="false" 
                             cg-read-only="true">
                            <span id="control" class="" ng-bind="vt_query.main_customer_name"></span>
                            <!-- ngIf: false -->
                        </div>
                        <div name="mimicEdit" 
                             class="clearfix " 
                             cg-bind="vt_query.vc_display_address" 
                             cg-key="vt_query/vc_display_address" 
                             cg-label="false" 
                             cg-read-only="true">
                            <span id="control" class="" ng-bind="vt_query.vc_display_address">2 KTAKA KTAKA BLORE </span>
                            <!-- ngIf: false -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </cg-template>
    </td>
    <td class="col-sm-4 layoutColumn">
        <div name="mimicEdit" 
             class="clearfix " 
             cg-bind="vt_query.specialty" 
             cg-key="vt_query/specialty" 
             cg-label="false" 
             cg-read-only="true">
            <span id="control" class="" ng-bind="vt_query.specialty">Aerospace Medicine</span>
            <!-- ngIf: false -->
        </div>
        <div name="mimicEdit" 
             class="clearfix " 
             cg-bind="vt_query.department_name" 
             cg-key="vt_query/department_name" 
             cg-label="false" 
             cg-read-only="true">
            <span id="control" class="" ng-bind="vt_query.department_name"></span>
            <!-- ngIf: false -->
        </div>
        <div name="mimicEdit" 
             class="clearfix " 
             cg-bind="vt_query.role" 
             cg-key="vt_query/role" 
             cg-label="false" 
             cg-read-only="true">
            <span id="control" class="" ng-bind="vt_query.role"></span>
            <!-- ngIf: false -->
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col-sm-3 layoutColumn">
        <div name="mimicEdit" 
             class="clearfix " 
             cg-bind="vt_query.phone_number" 
             cg-key="vt_query/phone_number" 
             cg-label="false" 
             cg-read-only="true">
            <span id="control" class="" ng-bind="vt_query.phone_number"></span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Please post the traceback.

Comment: Why do you have all of your code commented out with <!-- and --> ?

Comment: Please refer stack trace Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: repeater(vt_query in bo.data.vt_query).column(vt_query.display_name) didn't have any matching elements at this place in the DOM
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'BL2WHK134BS', ip: '10.205.34.53', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'

Comment: Does anyone has solution for it?